# Inconsistency between JLabel and JTextField when ComponentOrientation set to RTL

Tags: java, swing, right-to-left

I have a strange problem regarding Right-To-Left component orientation in swing - there is an inconsistency between JLabel and JTextField regarding the display of the same value.
Attached is an SSCCE that demos the problem.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class GuiTest2 extends JFrame
{
    public GuiTest2()
    {
        super( "Test" );

        JLabel testLabel = new JLabel();
        testLabel.setComponentOrientation( ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT );
        testLabel.setText( "ca 12 בדיקה" );
        testLabel.setBorder( new LineBorder( Color.BLACK ) );

        JTextField testTextField = new JTextField();
        testTextField.setComponentOrientation( ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT );
        testTextField.setText( "ca 12 בדיקה" );
        testTextField.setBorder( new LineBorder( Color.BLACK ) );

        JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout( 5, 5) );
        panel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder( 10, 10, 10, 10 ) );
        panel.add( testLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        panel.add( testTextField, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        setContentPane( panel );
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new GuiTest2();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of the above code:
[image: 1]
Shouldn't the result strings be the same?

without the `setComponentOrientation` I have the following (which ***are*** the same):
[image: 2]

Comment: according to Javadocs :The ComponentOrientation class encapsulates the language-sensitive orientation that is to be used to order the elements of a component or of text. The reason behind this strange behavior may be the language you have used for the display value.

Comment: it works perfect for  english only words.

Comment: seems odd that the same language is used for the two components but they both render differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `JLabel` ignores `componentOrientation`.

The slightly longer answer...

Whether text is ultimately rendered as base LTR or base RTL depends on logic in `TextLine`. In the case that there are attributes on the text, and the attributes include information about bidirectional embedding, this information is used to set the default text direction. This is usually present for components like `JTextPane`, and `JTextField`, being based on a `Document` as well, probably has the same behaviour (although before today, I was unaware of JTextField and JTextArea having any attributes at all, this one would make some kind of sense.)

In the case that the information is absent, the logic which figures it out from the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm (UAX #9) is in `java.text.Bidi`. The algorithm is as complicated as heck, but essentially if your line doesn't start with a strongly RTL character, the line will be assumed LTR by default.

Arguably, `setComponentOrientation()` is supposed to tell the renderer to change that default, so I'm viewing this as a Java bug.

One workaround (assuming you control the construction of all labels in your application!) is to insert a \u202E at the start of your text:

```
    String text = "\u202Eca 12 \u05D1\u05D3\u05D9\u05E7\u05D4";

    JLabel testLabel = new JLabel();
    testLabel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT );
    testLabel.setText(text);
    testLabel.setBorder( new LineBorder( Color.BLACK ) );
```

[image: screenshot of new behaviour]

How you insert the string depends on what's convenient:

1. Check all usages of setText and if any of them might start with non-RTL characters, insert the character.
2. Look at all string formats in your resource bundles and if any of them might start with non-RTL characters, insert the character into the message format. (This sounds like a good solution when you control the strings but isn't as great when you hit this issue in a third-party library.)
3. Replace `JLabel` with a subclass which works around the issue. This would work for all LAFs, but again, if you hit a problem in a third-party library, you'd have to convince them to apply a similar fix.
4. Replace `BasicLabelUI` with a fixed subclass and so on for every other LAF you intend to support. This is a pain in terms of repetition, but the fix would work automatically for any third-party usage of labels.

Or of course, any of the above could be applied on a case-by-case basis as you discover problems.